# How to represent linear types in C#/.Net?

Tags: .net, linear-types

Is there a reasonable way to express the concept of a [linear type](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LinearTypes) in .Net (Compact Framework/desktop 3.5 common subset), in such a way that (a) the required syntax doesn't become overly verbose, convoluted, or otherwise painful and (b) the invariant can be either enforced at run time or validated by code analysis at compile time (so a maintenance programmer in an all-fired hurry can't just blithely ignore the invariant)?  The idea here is to avoid the need for defensive copying of [command objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CommandPattern) at subsystem boundaries.

Comment: Would just using an immutable object suffice? Seems much simpler? I am not aware of anything that would do the necessary code analysis here

Comment: @Marc "Popsicle" immutability (composing a mutable object subgraph then "freezing" it against further mutation) might work.  I could probably roll up a FxCop rule to verify that easily enough.

Comment: What about the Freezable class?  Or is it not applicable in your use case?

Comment: @Jeffrey - I *routinely* use popsicle immutability; *so* much easier than a "builder" class.

Comment: @Mike Thanks for the tip!  Very interesting class.  It's part of WPF which is not supported in Compact Framework, though, so I'd have to reimplement it, possibly without the dependency properties and change notification baggage, and with finer context distinction than per-thread.

Comment: @Jeffrey no worries sorry for ignoring the Compact Framework requisite, I should have read the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two kinds of types in .Net: reference types and value types.

When you copy a reference type by assigning it to another variable, just the reference is copied.

When you copy a value type, the whole content of the type is copied, byte by byte.

In both cases, there is no way to prevent, modify or get notification about it (in contrast with C++'s copy constructors). What that means is that you can't implement linear types in .Net.

Your can instead use immutable (or freezable) type, as others suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Linear types, based on the theory of linear logic, and closely related to uniqueness types, are types assigned to values having the property that they have one and only one reference to them at all times. These are valuable for describing large immutable values such as files, strings, and so on.

An immutable type is one whose internal state cannot change after it has been instantiated.

A ‘deeply immutable’ type is one whose dependency graph contains reference types that are also ‘deeply immutable’.  If dependant reference types are not themselves ‘deeply immutable’, the type is termed ‘shallow immutable’.

In C# we work with reference types and value types.  Instances of reference types can be shared between disparate concurrently executing code, whereas value types are stack bound (unless boxed), copied on sharing and therefore autonomous, although not immutable (and may contain dependencies on other reference types which are then ‘copy shared’).

Although the ability to share a reference type is undoubtedly a powerful feature of object orientated frameworks, in the world of Enterprise development it should also be considered one of its main weaknesses and used with extreme caution.  Anything that cannot be executed atomically exposes fragility and an opportunity for interleaving bugs to intermittently wreak havoc.

In C# the best we can do is describe our intentions.  Immutability can be partially implemented by marking a types entire internal state as private and readonly.  Deep immutability cannot be enforced (nor for that matter can shallow) so it is up to the developer to stick to the intentions.  Changes to the state is through static methods that return new instances of the type containing the requested state.

```
public sealed class PersonImmutable {

    private readonly int _age;
    private readonly string _name;

    public PersonImmutable(int age, string name) { 
        this._age = age;
        this._name = name;
    }

    public int Age {
        get { return this._age; }
    }

    public string Name {
        get { return this._name; }
    }

    public static PersonImmutable NotifyBirthday(PersonImmutable source) {
        return new PersonImmutable(1 + source.Age, source.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so you've got an immutable type. How does that help you create linear type?

Comment: Memory Management is a key in defining a linear type of objects. Memory management for immutable objects is more efficient because immutable object memory is of fixed dimensions and is either used or available. So if these kind of types can very well be used for Linear Data Structures. The memory manager does not have to split the memory, expand the memory, or do any of the expensive operations that most memory managers do currently. These assumptions use linear mathematics and greatly speed up allocations and freeing.

Comment: Ok, that may be true in a system that recognizes linear types. But .Net doesn't, and so the speed is the same as when using mutable type. And the OP seemed to be more interested about the fact that you can be sure that there is ever only one reference to an object, which your immutable type doesn't enforce in any way.

Comment: Since .Net won't recognize the linear types, we are making the same to immuatble so that while doing operation we use the same and while representing we can represent the linear type in graphical format or in any other format. For example circle can be explained to .Net as a series of points, so operation on this will becoome easy as circle now represents an array.

Answer (score -1):

The provided link really defines LinearVariable, which could be defined similar to this:

```vb
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer On 

<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay("{_state}: {_value}")> _
Class LinearVariable(Of T)
  Private Enum State
   Unassigned
   Assigned
   Used
 End Enum
 Private _state As State = State.Unassigned
 Private _value As T
 Public Sub New()
  'Allow creation and later assignment
 End Sub
 Public Sub New(ByVal Value As T)
  _value = Value
  _state = State.Assigned
 End Sub
 Public Shared Widening Operator CType(Value As T) As LinearVariable(Of T)
  Return New LinearVariable(Of T)(Value)
 End Operator
 Public Shared Widening Operator CType(Value As LinearVariable(Of T)) As T
  Return Value.Value
 End Operator
 Public Property Value As T
  Get
   If _state = State.Assigned Then
    _state = State.Used
#If DEBUG Then
    Return _value
#Else ' Release - free the reference immedately after use
    value = _value
    _value = Nothing
#End If
   End If
   If _state = State.Unassigned Then _
    Throw New NullReferenceException("LinearVariable is unassigned")
   If _state = State.Used Then _
    Throw New AccessViolationException("LinearVariable has already been accessed")
   Throw New InvalidOperationException
  End Get
  Set(ByVal Value As T)
   ' May want to check _state, although the "definition" at http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LinearTypes seems to allow multiple writes
   _value = Value
   _state = State.Assigned
  End Set
 End Property
End Class
```

<sub>(This has been compiled but untested.)</sub>

This obviously only works at run time. I cannot think of any way of trying to enforce exactly one use of `.Value` at compile time.

Note that you could make `LinearVariable` `IDisposable` and then catch at run time when its value is set and not used.

Comment: This doesn't provide for catching alias references to the LinearVariable wrapper itself, nor does it provide any way to defend against retaining a reference to an object assigned into the variable.

Comment: @JeffreyHantin: True, and as I said it is only a runtime effort. I'm pretty sure you'd need compiler support to get any of those things. Specifically, you may be able to get an FxCop rule that notices aliasing of a `LinearVariable` (effectively it should ONLY exist as variable declarations and not as parameters to routines) and similarly for retaining the contents of the `.Value`, though you would have no control over the compiler storing the `.Value` in a temporary anonymous local variable.

Comment: Note that the title of the question includes "C#".

Comment: @Reinderien: I read it as C# _or_ .NET, and it didn't have C# as a tag -- not that that would have necessarily stopped me from posting this: VB.NET is convertable to C# by anyone who cares. (I say this because it is usually said the other way around.)